# How can I get value entered in to kendo grid date filter input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

In my grid I have a `FromDate` field formatted as `MM/yyyy`, and in the grid of the data source, the `FromDate` value is in `MM/dd/yyyy` format. The date is always the first day of the month, so I used jQuery code to set the date value to the first day of the month if the user selects any date using a grid filter calendar or a date picker.

For example, if the user selects or manually enters `11/25/2020` using either the date picker or the keyboard, the jQuery code below sets the date to the first day as `11/1/2020`, which works fine. But the problem is if the user enters or types in the date manually in `MM/yyyy` format or, let's say, enters `11/2020` then nothing happens.

[image]

how can I get value entered in to kendo grid date filter input field to apply the same logic below?

```js
if (e.filter.filters[0].field === "FromDate" ) {

    var fromDate = e.filter.filters[0].value
    var month = fromDate.getMonth();
    var year = fromDate.getFullYear();

    var firstDateOfTheMonth = new Date(year, month + 1);
    var lastDay = firstDateOfTheMonth.getDate();
    fromDate.setDate(lastDay);

    console.log(e.filter.filters[0]);

    var formattedFromDate = moment(fromDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
    var productsGrid= $("#ProductsGrid").data("kendoGrid");

    productsGrid.dataSource.filter({
        field: e.filter.filters[0].field,
        operator: e.filter.filters[0].operator,
        value: formattedFromDate
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you make this runnable ?

Answer (score 1):

Use datepicker change event to trigger your function

```
$("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker({
 change: function() {
    var value = this.value();
    // logic here
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i fixed smilar problem by this in the grid

```js
        ->parameterMap('function(options, operation) {

                        
if (options.hasOwnProperty("filter")){
//console.log(options.filter.filters);
var filtre=options.filter.filters;
   for(i=0;i<filtre.length;i++){
       //console.log(filtre[i].field);
       if(filtre[i].field=="date"){
       filtre[i].value=kendo.toString(filtre[i].value,"yyyy-MM-dd");
      // console.log(kendo.toString(filtre[i].value,"yyyy-MM-dd"));
        }
   }
}

            return kendo.stringify(options);
         }'

   );
```